# markdown-it-textual-uml and vitepress-sidebar coexistence possible?

Tags: vue.js, vite, vitepress

I am trying to use both `markdown-it-textual-uml` and `vitepress-sidebar` plugins in my project.

I started including `markdown-it-textual-uml` and all was well.

Then I tried to add `vitepress-sidebar` and apparently, being an ESM module, it needs `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. Unfortunately this broke `markdown-it-textual-uml` which now complains about:

```
Error: Dynamic require of "file:///home/mcon/projects/@@SITE/node_modules/markdown-it-textual-uml/src/index.js" is not supported
```

My tentative and very partial `config.ts` is:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitepress'
import { generateSidebar } from 'vitepress-sidebar'

export default defineConfig({
  title: "Mauro Condarelli personal site",
  description: "A random collection of unrelated projects",
  themeConfig: {
    nav: [
      { text: 'Home', link: '/' },
      { text: 'Examples', link: '/markdown-examples' }
    ],

    sidebar: generateSidebar({
      // use defaults
    }),

    socialLinks: [
      { icon: 'github', link: 'https://github.com/vuejs/vitepress' }
    ]
  },
  
  markdown : {
    config: (md) => {
      md.use(require("markdown-it-textual-uml"));
      md.use(require("markdown-it-deflist"));
    }
  }

})
```

while my almost-default `package.json` is:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "docs:dev": "vitepress dev vitepress",
    "docs:build": "vitepress build vitepress",
    "docs:preview": "vitepress preview vitepress"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "markdown-it-deflist": "^2.1.0",
    "markdown-it-textual-uml": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.3.2",
    "vitepress-sidebar": "^1.8.1"
  }
}
```

How can I fix this (if at all possible)?

Note: while I'm an experienced programmer I'm not deep in JavaScript and friends, I'm just learning and I still don't really grock it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you requiring it? Just import it:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitepress';
// @ts-ignore
import markdownItTextualUml from 'markdown-it-textual-uml';

export default defineConfig({
  markdown: {
    config(md) {
      md.use(markdownItTextualUml);
    },
  },
})
```

This would work even if you set `type: module` in your package.json.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-i24rds

Comment: I did things that way because it is how VitePress [site](ttps://vitepress.dev/guide/markdown#advanced-configuration) says I should do them. As I am on JavaScript since about a week I tend to stick to docs ;)  I will try your way ASAP. Thanks.